# pgbouncer and scram-sha-256 setup -postgres 16 and pgbouncer version PgBouncer 1.20.1

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

postgres 16 and  pgbouncer version  PgBouncer 1.20.1 - windows 2022 standard server

I cannot via pgbouncer to postgres db using SCRAM Authentication

auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM pgbouncer.user_lookup($1)  - that is the auth query in the pgbouncer.ini file . The above function does  exist in postgres db

userlist does exist

connection user  - pgbouncer1

debug log from pgbouncer
C-0000000001737370: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.199.32.78:56885 got var: user=pgbouncer1

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.199.32.78:56885 got var: database=test1

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.199.32.78:56885 using application_name: psql

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.199.32.78:56885 got var: client_encoding=WIN1252

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] LOG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 login attempt: db=test1 user=pgbouncer1 tls=no

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE safe_send(752, 24) = 24

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 **Auth request sent successfully**

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE resync(752): done=86, parse=86, recv=86

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE resync(752): done=0, parse=0, recv=0

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE safe_recv(752, 4096) = 55

2024-02-23 13:23:26.280 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 read pkt='p' len=55

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 C: selected SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 SCRAM client-first-message = "n,,n=,r=+PvdxjXs9rPf51A7qzgzwNg4"

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 stored secret = "test"

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 SCRAM server-first-message = "r=+PvdxjXs9rPf51A7qzgzwNg44Ha8cjSOvwds//spe8vBNWap,s=WLD0nJV050QdHzOFRN25+g==,i=4096"

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE safe_send(752, 93) = 93

2024-02-23 13:23:26.296 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE resync(752): done=55, parse=55, recv=55

2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE resync(752): done=0, parse=0, recv=0

2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE safe_recv(752, 4096) = 109

2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] NOISE C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.
32.78:56885 read pkt='p' len=109
2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 SCRAM client-final-message =
"c=biws,r=+PvdxjXs9rPf51A7qzgzwNg44Ha8cjSOvwds//spe8vBNWap,p=KOOb7pVVrgOw1qLLLiyZX6L3dwehylP5d+nChuP1X/U="

2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] DEBUG C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 SCRAM client-final-message-without-proof = "c=biws,r=+PvdxjXs9rPf51A7qzgzwNg44Ha8cjSOvwds//spe8vBNWap"

2024-02-23 13:23:26.327 Pacific Standard Time [10300] ERROR C-0000000001737370: test1/pgbouncer1@10.199.32.78:56885 password authentication failed

scram authentication process is happening - why is it failing